# Google Maps API street length

Tags: java, javascript, mysql, google-maps, maps

i'd love to know if in the google maps api exists a method to find street start and end.
I'm looking for something that adds a marker in every intersection and adds it to a mySQL DB in order to do computations over it, like Dijkstra's algorithm. 
I was thinking about using the house number, but it's inaccurate and tedious, not talking about computational needs.. 
Any clue would be really appreciated

Comment: Have a look at http://www.openstreetmap.org

Comment: This is off-topic for SO; it has nothing to do with programming. You should be asking this on the Google Maps API forum?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Andomar for the tip, i've solved the whole problem that limited my project.
I've used OpenStreetMap and Spatialite, which thanks to [this](http://www.lex-web.net/using-osm-data-for-routing/) article i've set up in no time. 
It can even be solved using stored procedures like in [this](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/qrytip.php?id=766) other article.